# Couldn't resolve module/action 'k8s_exec' on Ansible Playbook

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, cloud, rancher

I am trying to make a reboot to a pod on a Rancher Cluster through Ansible and I am having this error:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'k8s_exec'. This often indicates a misspelling,                                                                                                        missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/ansible/GetKubectlPods': line 27, column 7,                                                                                                        but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    -
      name: Reboot Machine
      ^ here
```

I don't know why I am getting an error since I am also using k8s_info and he is working be fine.

Here is the playbook I am running:

```
--- 

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: root

  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'

  tasks:
    -
      name: Get the pods in the specific namespace
      k8s_info:
        kubeconfig: '/etc/ansible/RCCloudConfig'
        kind: Pod
        namespace: redmine
      register: pod_list

    -
      name: Print pod names 
      debug:
         msg: "pod_list: {{ pod_list | json_query('resources[*].status.podIP')  }} "

    - set_fact:
        pod_names: "{{pod_list|json_query('resources[*].metadata.name')}}"
    -
      name: Reboot Machine
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: '/etc/ansible/RCCloudConfig'
        namespace: redmine
        pod: redmine_quick-testing-6c57cc5d65-lwkww #pod name
        command: reboot
```

Ansible Version:

```
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

In case I edit my playbook and add the `community.kubernetes collection`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/__init__.py:12: DeprecationWarning: The package kubernetes.client.apis is renamed and deprecated, use kubernetes.client.api instead (please note that the trailing s was removed).\n  DeprecationWarning\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py\", line 296, in websocket_call\n    client = WSClient(configuration, get_websocket_url(url), headers, capture_all)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py\", line 94, in __init__\n    self.sock.connect(url, header=header)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py\", line 226, in connect\n    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py\", line 80, in handshake\n    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py\", line 165, in _get_resp_headers\n    raise WebSocketBadStatusException(\"Handshake status %d %s\", status, status_message, resp_headers)\nwebsocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 404 Not Found\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1592530746.4685414-46123-84159696554463/AnsiballZ_k8s_exec.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1592530746.4685414-46123-84159696554463/AnsiballZ_k8s_exec.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1592530746.4685414-46123-84159696554463/AnsiballZ_k8s_exec.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.kubernetes.plugins.modules.k8s_exec', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k8s_exec_payload_q6oom26c/ansible_k8s_exec_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/kubernetes/plugins/modules/k8s_exec.py\", line 148, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k8s_exec_payload_q6oom26c/ansible_k8s_exec_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/kubernetes/plugins/modules/k8s_exec.py\", line 135, in main\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/stream.py\", line 35, in stream\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py\", line 841, in connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec\n    (data) = self.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info(name, namespace, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py\", line 941, in connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info\n    collection_formats=collection_formats)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py\", line 345, in call_api\n    _preload_content, _request_timeout)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py\", line 176, in __call_api\n    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/stream.py\", line 30, in _intercept_request_call\n    return ws_client.websocket_call(config, *args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py\", line 302, in websocket_call\n    raise ApiException(status=0, reason=str(e))\nkubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (0)\nReason: Handshake status 404 Not Found\n\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Solution:

Find your `k8s_exec.py` file and edit your import settings from `Kubernetes.apis` to `Kubernetes.api`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no way we can help you troubleshoot a 404 without more details, starting with whether `kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/ansible/RCCloudConfig -n redmine exec redmine_quick-testing-6c57cc5d65-lwkww -- ls -l` succeeds or not. The `exec` and `logs` verbs use an entirely different protocol than the rest of the kubernetes verbs, so there are a lot of ways they can go wrong

Comment: I've already solved the problem bove by modifying the k8s_exec.py file and changing the API name. My big thing now is that I am not being able to run extend commands to the pods with k8s_exec command. If I pass him a "ls /opt", for example, I can't retrieve anything because of the way how command works. Any possible solutions?

Comment: Can you post your solution to issue mentioned in question as an answer? Second part of your reply is another topic so it should be asked as separate question.